# Routing for a PHP file from React+Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, axios, next.js

Im created a contact form on React.js + Next.js. It looks like this:

```js
<div className="contact-form">
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" required value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" className="form-control" required placeholder="Email" required value={this.state.email} onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" required className="form-control" placeholder="Phone" value={this.state.phone_number} onChange={e => this.setState({ phone_number: e.target.value })}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="msg_subject" id="msg_subject" className="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required value={this.state.msg_subject} onChange={e => this.setState({ msg_subject: e.target.value })}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <textarea name="message" className="form-control" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })} value={this.state.message}></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} value="Submit">Send</button>
                        </div>
                        {this.state.mailSent &&
                        <div>Thank you for contcting us.</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And created a handler that will send data to a PHP file using Axios:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const API_PATH = 'http://localhost:3000/index.php';

class ContactForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            phone_number: '',
            msg_subject: '',
            message: '',
            mailSent: false,
            error: null
        }
    }

    handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${API_PATH}`,
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            data: this.state
        })
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    mailSent: result.data.sent
                })
            })
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
    };
```

But when I try to do this, I get a 404 error. I have tried creating different folders and accessing them through the browser, but always get redirected to error 404. Please help me implement the correct design so that I can access the file from this need? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Problem is in PHP, not javascript.

Are you able to load any php page in localhost?

Comment: most likely you are running Next.js in port 3000 and php server in a different port 8000. Search in stackoverflow or google on how to use php with next.js

Comment: changed the port, nothing has changed...